# Configure vsftpd allow access to mounted ISO file

Tags: mount, ftp, selinux, vsftpd

I am having problems to allow anonymous FTP access to a directory that mounted a ISO file.

- No change to `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`
- RHEL 6.5 DVD ISO file saved to `/var/ftp/pub/ISO/rhel6_5.iso`
- Anonymous user can see this ISO file
- Created a directory `/var/ftp/pub/rhel`
- Mounted iso file, `mount -o loop,ro /var/ftp/pub/ISO/rhel6_5.iso /var/ftp/pub/rhel`

But anonymous ftp users can't see `rhel` directory for some reason, any ideas ?

I followed this instructions [vsftpd symbolic link](http://radu.cotescu.com/vsftpd-and-symbolic-links/), but it did not work for me. `/var/ftp/pub/rhel` directory will disappear from anonymous FTP user, if I mount the ISO file.

Here is `ls -lZ` output. I also noticed that SELinux context will change once I mount the ISO file.

```
[root@citest pub]# ls -lZ
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0 ISO
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0 rhel
```

Comment: What permission have the `/var/ftp/pub/rhel` directory?

Answer (score 2):

After about 3 hours, I think I figured out why it is not working.

Selinux context `public_content_t` is required for files shared via an FTP server, unless associated with a user home directory and looks like `/var/ftp/pub` does not qualify for home directory.

After I mounted ISO file, the security context of rhel changed to `system_u:object_r:iso9660_t:s0` and also because ISO file can only be mounted as read only, I could not change security context.

Also noticed following in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1404397698.292:182): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=2671 comm="vsftpd" path="/pub/ISO/rhel" dev=loop1 ino=1856 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:ftpd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:iso9660_t:s0 tclass=dir
```

Disabled selinux and restarted vsftpd, all working fine.

Comment: Is it possible to mount iso file with selinux context ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a VM that has connected a iso image as virtual cdrom, that's almost the same as your setup.

I added this line to `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/cdrom /repo iso9660 rootcontext=system_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0,context=system_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0 0 0
```

Search in mount(8) for selinux options

ftp user setup:

```
# getent passwd ftp
ftp:x:14:50:FTP User:/repo:/sbin/nologin
```

Comment: At night, all cats are gray, and, to a VM, a virtual CD is the same as a real CD.  (I assume that you're talking about an ISO image file *on the host*.)  I doubt that this is "almost the same" as loopback-mounting a local ISO file.

Comment: Let's kill that cat. On the host: mount -o loop,rootcontext=system_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0,context=system_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0 ./CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1503-01.iso /repo